# I want to delete rows of a csv file which contain " / " in it using python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to delete rows of a csv file which contain " / " in it.

```
import csv
with open("test.csv", 'r') as infile , open("test2.csv", 'w') as outfile:
    reader=csv.reader(infile)
    writer=csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in reader:
        if "/" not in line:
            writer.writerow(line)
```

This not working .
Sample data

- 182 /api/PostAppDetails?loanSeqId=12067,1,12.136
- 182 /api/PostAppDetails?loanSeqId=12068,1,17.509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data makes me wonder why you are treating them as CSV files

Can't you just do

```
with open("test.csv", 'r') as infile , open("test2.csv", 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if "/" not in line: 
            outfile.write(line)
```

Note: your code is probably failing because the CSV code is returning a line as an array of strings. So you are checking if the array has one element equal to "/"

Comment: I just updated my sample data. I want to delete the full row if "/" is anywhere in that row.

Comment: Yeah. Still not sure why you need to treat it as a CSV if that is your criteria

Comment: Then what i have to do

Comment: Have you tried my code snippet?  Treat it as a normal file, read it line by line and check if / exists in the line at all